# Nose: test all modules in a given package

Tags: python, testing, nose

I have a package with several sub-packages, one of them for tests (named `tests`). Since the sub-package name makes it clear that contained modules are test modules, I prefer not to pollute module names with the test-name pattern nose expects to include them for testing. That's the setup I'm thinking of:

```
- foo
  - __init__.py
  ...
  - bar
    - __init__.py
    ...
  - baz
    - __init__.py
    ...
  - tests
    - __init__.py
    - something.py
```

Now, by default nose does not run tests found in `foo.tests.something`. I know nose accepts the `-i` option to define regular expressions for additional stuff to search tests in. So `nose -i something`  does the job here. However, I have a bunch of modules in the `tests` package and do not want to name them explicitely. `nose -i tests\..*` does not work, it looks like nose only matches against module base-names. As a last resort I could run `nose --all-modules`, but this also inspects `foo.bar` and `foo.baz` -- I'd like to avoid this.

So, how could I instruct nose to look for tests in all modules within a given package (`tests` in my case)? I could write a nose plugin for this task, but I'm looking for a standard solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to import the files into your `__init__.py` and have them picked up. I had this setup:

```
- app:
  - __init__.py
  - models.py
  - views.py
  - tests:
    - __init__.py
    - models.py # contain tests
    - views.py # contain tests
```

In the `tests/__init__.py` file I had the following:

```
from app.tests.models import *
from app.tests.views import *
```

Which defeats one of the benefits of using a regex to find tests (a goal of nose) but worked.

You can also use the decorator `@istest` to flag an individual def as a test if you want to avoid the naming of methods to match the regex. I've not tried to do this for modules (py files) that don't also match the regex but I doubt it would work without the above import.

Note, I've moved away from the import in `__init__.py` and just prefix my test methods and filenames with test_ and postfix my classes with Test. I find this makes the code more self-describing as even in a Test class there may be setup methods and helper methods (e.g. generators).

Comment: The init import is a neat idea. However, meanwhile I also use `test_` prefixes for test modules. I do not really like that but it avoids confusion when working with other developers who expect the standard naming scheme.

Answer (score 4):

If you name the files in tests with a `test_` prefix (i.e. rename `something.py` to `test_something.py`, running nose should pick them up by default.

You say "I prefer not to pollute module names with the test-name pattern nose expects to include them for testing", but "something" isn't descriptive of the file, because the file tests that something. What's the problem with using the non-confusing, standard way of naming your tests?

Comment: Yes, I know that naming the modules `test_...` works, but IMHO it is redundant as the package `tests`, which contains the modules, indicates that they are test-modules -- kind of a conflict with the DRY principle. You might say not all modules in a `tests` package necessarily have to be tests, but in that case a `__test__ = False` attribute also does the job. That's my rationale and my question is if nose somehow supports such a setup or not.

Answer (score -1):

with Nose:

```
nosetests --all-modules
```

With py.test it can be done by put this in *setup.cfg* (configure file):

```
[pytest]
python_files=*.py
```

check this doc: [pytest docs](http://pytest.org/latest/example/pythoncollection.html).

Comment: Well, I mentioned the `--all-modules` option already in my question, along with a reasons why this is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Also, I am in looking for good way to test.  Currently I `cd ./my/test/module`, then `py.test or nosetests`.  When it can not work, and time's short, I stop use it, instead try `print...`, and `python myscript.py`.  This is not framework way.